# AES 256 CBC string decryption using only secret key

Tags: java, encryption, mule, mulesoft

I am creating one API in Mulesoft where i will get one parameter say **payment_id** in encrypt form from the url. encrption was done using the AES-256-CBC algorithm.

I have to **decrypt** this payment_id in my API. I have below input:

```
encryptedString as payment_id
secretKey to decrypt the payment_id
```

I don't have any IV init vector or password. I tried to use the crypto module in Mulesoft for decryption but didn't found that above information are not sufficient.

I also tried to use the Java to decrypt by everywhere it was required IV init vector and key is generating and they are not using the stored key.

I also tried to use the online website tool to decrypt the the data using above information and it is correctly decrypted there that shows that i have enough information.

can anybody tell me if i can decrypt using any way in Mulesoft or through Java.

In case something is not clear, please let me know

Comment: Try an all zero IV, or try to use the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext as IV. You also need to validate the padding mode, try and use *no padding* during decryption and print out the last block (using hexadecimals) to find out the type of padding.

Comment: Please provide the configuration you used in Mule and the Java code used for reference. Also please provide details of the online site you mentioned. It is not clear if you used IV or not, or if it is required.

Comment: website used is https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption. In Mule, i have used crypto module as JCE decrypt module where i have used as a cipher as a secret key